# Rake synthesized tasks and file date checking

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile

I have a Rakefile I'm using to generate HTML from markdown (and do some other stuff that's irrelevant to the question.

I'm generating files from my source, .feature files (in the FileList `DOCUMENTS`), into my output directory `OUTPUT` as HTML. I have an `htmlfile` method to assemble and write my HTML file.

I'm trying two alternative options here:

File tasks:

```
DOCUMENTS.each do |doc|
  file doc.pathmap("#{OUTPUT}/%X.html") => doc do |t|
    htmlfile t.name, RDiscount.new(F.read doc).to_html, t.name.pathmap('%n')
  end
end
```

Synthesized file tasks with a rule:

```
rule '.html' => proc {|html| html.pathmap("%{#{OUTPUT}/,}X.feature")} do |t|
  htmlfile t.name, RDiscount.new(F.read t.source).to_html, t.name.pathmap('%n')
end
```

My understanding was that the latter option would synthesize file tasks, and have the same net effect. However I find that if I choose it, it does not cope with incremental building, whereas the first option does.

If I build, then modify one file, then run rake --trace I get the following:

With synthesized tasks:

```
** Invoke output/Module/Feature.html (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke output/Module (not_needed)
```

And with the explicit file tasks:

```
** Invoke output/Module/Feature.html (first_time)
** Invoke output/Module (not_needed)
** Invoke Module/Feature.feature (first_time, not_needed)
** Execute output/Module/Feature.html
```

This option is clearly checking the source file. I thought linking output and source was exactly what rule

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I believe it's most helpful to put the answer as an actual answer, rather than a comment. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68507/what-to-do-if-you-find-the-answer-to-your-own-question)

It turns out that if you have `file outdoc => something` elsewhere in your Rakefile, it will mess with synthesized tasks. Whereas if you have file tasks for those output documents it adds to the pre-requisites and works fine. This sort of makes sense; synthesized tasks don't really exist.

I also found out that rules only work to one level of inference ( http://onestepback.org/articles/buildingwithrake/rulelimitations.html) though that didn't turn out to be the answer.

Fix: rearrange pre-requisites of tasks, or use the explicit file tasks.